# mysql2 gem installation failes on CentOS 6.4 x64 with MySQL 5.6

Tags: mysql, ruby, rubygems, mysql2, centos6

Trying to install mysql2 gem on CentOS 6.4 x64 with MySQL 5.6 installed with rpm.

Getting this:

```
    Installing mysql2 (0.3.11)
    Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

            /usr/local/rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p448/bin/ruby extconf.rb
    checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... yes
    checking for rb_wait_for_single_fd()... yes
    checking for mysql.h... yes
    checking for errmsg.h... yes
    checking for mysqld_error.h... yes
    creating Makefile

    make
    compiling mysql2_ext.c
    compiling result.c
    compiling client.c
    client.c: In function Б─≤rb_raise_mysql2_errorБ─≥:
    client.c:98: warning: ISO C90 forbids mixed declarations and code
    client.c: In function Б─≤rb_mysql_client_socketБ─≥:
    client.c:590: warning: ISO C90 forbids mixed declarations and code
    linking shared-object mysql2/mysql2.so
    /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lmysqlclient_r
    collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
    make: *** [mysql2.so] Error 1


    Gem files will remain installed in /usr/local/rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.3.11 for inspection.
    Results logged to /usr/local/rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.3.11/ext/mysql2/gem_make.out

    An error occurred while installing mysql2 (0.3.11), and Bundler cannot continue.
    Make sure that `gem install mysql2 -v '0.3.11'` succeeds before bundling.
```

**EDIT:**

response from ldconfig -p | grep mysql

```
    libmysqlclient_r.so.16 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/libmysqlclient_r.so.16
    libmysqlclient_r.so.15 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/libmysqlclient_r.so.15
    libmysqlclient_r.so.14 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/libmysqlclient_r.so.14
    libmysqlclient_r.so.12 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/libmysqlclient_r.so.12
    libmysqlclient.so.16 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/libmysqlclient.so.16
    libmysqlclient.so.15 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/libmysqlclient.so.15
    libmysqlclient.so.14 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/libmysqlclient.so.14
    libmysqlclient.so.12 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/libmysqlclient.so.12
```

Answer (score 3):

Before doing anything I would recommend trying this:

```
sudo yum install mysql-devel
```

Comment: This worked for me, just ran into the same problem on a new VM build and after the mysql-devel install 'bundle install' worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

It seems it can't find the libmysql_r.so. Either it isn't installed or the system can't find it because it is not properly configured.
Can you list the MySQL packages you have installed?
Can you find the libmysqlclient_r.so on your system?
Can you give us the output of the `ldconfig -p|grep mysql`?

If the libmysqlclient_r.so file is not there, you probably don't have the MySQL-client packages installed.
If the proper packages are installed, the libmysqlclient_r.so can be found but it doesn't appear in the output of `ldconfig -p`, you can update the ldconfig cache by running `ldconfig -v`. It should pick up the library. Then try to install the gem again.

Comment: I edited the question and added the ouput from ldconfig -p | grep mysql.

Comment: So the library is installed. You should have a link to `libmysqlclient_r.so` like so: `libmysqlclient_r.so (libc6) => /usr/lib/libmysqlclient_r.so`. Can you run `ldconfig`to update the symlinks and then `ldconfig -p|grep mysql` again to check if you now have the one the gem is looking for: `libmysqlclient_r.so`.

Answer (score 1):

I also met the same problem.I solved it by `rpm -ivh MySQL-shared-5.6.30-1.el6.x86_64.rpm`.